# How to make http request in factory

Tags: angularjs

I want to get data from server using angular factory. Here is what I did.

```
.factory('Profile',function($http){
        return {
            getProfile: function(id){
                $http.get(httpUrl + 'vendors/detail?id=' + id).then(function(result){
                    return result.data;
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

And in controller I call `Profile` like so

```
.controller('profileCtrl', function($scope,$http,Profile){
        $scope.contact = function(id){
            $scope.vendor = Profile.getProfile(id);
            console.log($scope.vendor);
        }
}
```

But I always get `undefined` from the log. I'm expecting a `json` data returned from server. How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory method **getProfile()** doesn't return anything. The return inside the **.then()** of the $http.get returns that value to be used in the next **.then()**.

The best option is to return the entire $http call. Like so:

```
getProfile: function(id){
    return $http.get(httpUrl + 'vendors/detail?id=' + id).then(function(result){
        return result.data;
    });
}
```

You can keep the return inside, so that the next **.then()** you do will already have the correct parameters, without needing to do "result.data". Like so:

```
.controller('profileCtrl', function($scope,$http,Profile){
    $scope.contact = function(id){
        Profile.getProfile(id).then(function(response) {
            $scope.vendor = response;
            console.log($scope.vendor);
        });
    }
}
```

A $http call returns a promise which can be chained on. Everything you return inside a promise can be used in the next chain. [more info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: You should consider `DRY` and `KISS` principal. You have repeated code for `.then(function(result){})` i.e. `.then` one in `service` other in `controller`. At least If possible modify your code to avoid code duplication. Will Help others as well since its a chosen answer

Comment: @ShashankVivek I wouldn't apply that here. I think it's sloppy to just return the direct response from an $http call because it contains things like the status and headers. If I call a service I expect just that data and nothing else, the service itself can handle status codes and such. So in this case I cleaned up the response before sending it outside the service and this does require some extra code. In your case you would have duplicate code outside the services if you had to handle status codes and such.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that you are not handing the promise.

```
            $http.get(httpUrl + 'vendors/detail?id=' + id).then(function(result){
                return result.data;
            });
```

Here `return result.data;` is not a promise and so when you are handling it in controller, you are missing the response because its an asynchronous process (i.e. your data hasn't arrived from server yet) and so you get undefined
.

factory.js

```
  .factory('Profile',function($http){
    return {
        getProfile: function(id){
            return $http.get(httpUrl + 'vendors/detail?id=' + id);
        }
    }
 })
```

in `controller.js`

```
   .controller('profileCtrl', function($scope,$http,Profile){
    $scope.contact = function(id){
        Profile.getProfile(id).then(function(response){
           $scope.vendor = response.data;
     });
        console.log($scope.vendor);
    }
 }
```

#### OR

USE this if you want to manipulate response before sending to controller

```
  .factory('Profile',function($http,$q){
    return {
        getProfile: function(id){ 
            var  deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(httpUrl + 'vendors/detail?id=' + id).then(function(resp){ 
                // modify the "resp" and then return
                deferred.resolve(resp);
            },function( error ){
              deferred.reject(error);
          })
        }
       return deferred.promise;
    }
 })
```

in `controller.js`

```
   .controller('profileCtrl', function($scope,$http,Profile){
    $scope.contact = function(id){
        Profile.getProfile(id).then(function(response){
           $scope.vendor = response;
     });
        console.log($scope.vendor);
    }
 }
```

Comment: at the first clickthe first option returns `undefined` but the next click it returns the correct data. (this function is triggered by a click btw)

Comment: @Abaij: Yes because when you clicked first time, you made `http` req but the data never arrived from server. When you clicked again, the data was there now. I provided a detailed explanation with all possible variation and yet you chose the other one. Cheers. I hope my answer helped anyways.

Answer (score 0):

there's slight problem with the your code. By the time your `Profile.getProfile(id)` initializes `$scope.vendor` the `console.log($scope.vendor);` has already been executed, which is why you get `undefined`

what you want to do is `console.log($scope.vendor);` in the `then` of your factory.
Something like:-

```
Profile.getProfile(id) 
.then(function(response){ 
   $scope.vendor = response.data.value;
   console.log($scope.vendor);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you missing close your parentheses and maybe in your `factory` too, you need to call factory like this :

```
.controller('profileCtrl', ['$scope','$http','Profile',  
  function($scope,$http,Profile){
    $scope.contact = function(id){
        $scope.vendor = Profile.getProfile(id);
        console.log($scope.vendor);
    }
}]);
```

Hope this help